# Ito's lemma and Lognormal Property

Tags: options, option-pricing, itos-lemma, lognormal

What would be the difference between:

\begin{align}
dS = udt + \sigma dz 
\end{align}

and

\begin{align}
dS=u*S*dt + \sigma*S*dzdS 
\end{align}
Is that the former is in absolute terms and the latter is in relative terms with the stock price?

Therefore, if I want to derive the lognormal property for ( $G =\ln S => dG = (u-\sigma^2/2)*dt + \sigma*dz$) pricing an option, can the first equation be used and how? In John Hull book is done by using the second one.

Thank you.

Comment: The first SDE is arithmetic Brownian motion and can become negative. Stocks have limited liability, so a negative stock price is not very sensible for a model.

Comment: Does this mean that the first SDE cannot be used to come up  to the lognormal property? I have to use the second one?

Comment: The first process is just normally distributed with mean $ut$ and variance $\sigma^2 t$ - no $\log$s at all

Comment: To be a little more careful: $dS_t$ in the first equation is arithmetic Brownian motion -- so $dS_t$ and thus changes in $S$ are normally-distributed. The second equation should be $dS_t=uS_tdt+\sigma S_tdz$ and is geometric Brownian motion. Then, $dS_t$ is log-normal or (equivalently) $d(\log(S_t))=\frac{dS_t}{S_t}$ is normally-distributed as are changes in $\log(S)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to

\begin{align}
dS = \mu dt + \sigma dW_t
\end{align}
is simply

\begin{align}
S(t) - S(0) = \mu t + \sigma W_t
\end{align}

([as discussed here](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-s096-topics-in-mathematics-with-applications-in-finance-fall-2013/lecture-notes/MIT18_S096F13_lecnote21.pdf) in the first page, for example)

Comment: I understand this, thank you, but it doesn't fully answer my questions above, as I am a bit confused.

Comment: The first equation is a normal process, not a log-normal process

Comment: The first one it says is the instantaneous rate of return and the second one is the Brownian motion with drift followed by the stock price. Does it mean that the first one is in absolute terms and the second one in relative terms? And how do I come to the lognormal property with the first equation if possible?

Comment: The first equation says that the change in $dS$ has a drift that is linear in time, and a variance that is growing linearly with time. It is *NOT* log-normally distributed. Lognormal behaviour comes from geometric brownian motion (ie. the second equation) when the drift and variance terms have a factor of $S$ in them as well

Comment: In first equation we have constant drift, but in second constant return (drift/stock price) according to John Hull's book. Right? But this is the part I don't understand actually, why constant return? **u*S*dt** is expected increase now in **S**, not **u*dt**. How do I interpret **u*S** in other words?

Comment: The drift growth in $S$ is proportional to its current level (hence the 'geometric'), whereas for $\mu dt$ it is constant

Comment: $dS/S=\mu dt$.  dS/S is the relative performance.

Comment: @S_star: As dm63 pointed out, brownian motion models the stock price difference whereas geometric brownian motion  models the stock price return. It's necessary to model returns because they can become negative ( in the model ) which is fine. In the brownian motion model, stock price differences can become negative and this implies that the stock price itself can become negative which is not reasonable.

Comment: unlike rates and oil futures...

Comment: Thank you all!!

Comment: @StackG do you have any possible explanation regarding this: https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/57532/bootstrapping-swap-curve ?
Thank you!

Comment: Came back in that question - I need a bit more clarity on your context

Comment: @StackG Thanks for the equation above and I went through it again and is clear. However there is one more thing unclear:

**dS/S is normally distributed with (u*dt ; sigma^2 * dt)**

But also

**lnSt - lnS is normally distributed with (u - sigma^2 / 2)*dt ; sigma*dz**

What is the difference?

Comment: @markleeds Could you also give me an explanation what is  the difference between 

**dS/S is normally distributed with (udt ; sigma^2 * dt)** and  

**lnSt - lnS is normally distributed with (u - sigma^2 / 2)*dt ; sigmadz** ?

Comment: Hi: I think there's a typo in your dS/S variance but the difference between them is that the first is referring to the return of the stock price and the second is referring to the difference in the stock price.  The difference in stock price is not helpful because it doesn't prevent the stock price from going negative.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps it might help if we define the difference between Brownian Motion (BM) and Geometric Brownian Motion (GBM). BM has independent, identically distributed increments while GBM has independent, identically distributed ratios between successive factors. The definition is inherited from that of arithmetic random walks, which are modelled as sums of random terms, and geometric random walks, modelled as products of random factors.

Let's look at them a bit more in detail.

The BM differential equation is:

$dS_{t} = \mu dt + \sigma dW_{t}$

where the first term, $\mu dt$, is the drift term and the second term $ \sigma dW_{t}$ is the diffusion term characterised by the Wiener process $W_{t}$.

To resolve it, we add integrals on both sides:

$\int_{t=0}^T dS_{t} =\mu \int_{t=0}^T dt + \sigma \int_{t=0}^T  dW_{t}$

Here, the last term $\int_{t=0}^T  dW_{t}$ is your random variable, i.e. shock.

Let us now look at the GBM.  As we said earlier, the GBM is characterised by i.i.d
ratios between successive factors. We define it as

$ \frac{dS_{t}}{S_{t}} = \mu dt + \sigma dW_{t}$

Here, $ \frac{dS_{t}}{S_{t}}$ is the finite-time price. To resolve, we take logs and after applying ito's lemma we obtain

$d(logS_{t}) = (\mu - \frac{1}{2} \sigma^2)dt+\sigma dW_{t}$

now we can add integrals, as we have a normal diffusion:

$\int_{t=0}^Td(logS_{t}) = (\mu - \frac{1}{2} \sigma^2)\int_{t=0}^Tdt+\sigma \int_{t=0}^TdW_{t}$

hence

$log S_{T}-log S_{0} = (\mu - \frac{1}{2} \sigma^2)T + \sigma \int_{t=0}^TdW_{t}$

Here, $(\mu - \frac{1}{2} \sigma^2)T$ is the mean of the log price after T years, and $\sigma \int_{t=0}^TdW_{t}$ is the shock, i.e. the variance  after T years (normally distributed with mean 0 and variance 1).

Finally, we have the rate of return equal to

$\frac{S_{t}}{S_{0}} = exp((\mu - \frac{1}{2} \sigma^2)T + \sigma \int_{t=0}^TdW_{t})$

which is log-normally distributed.

I hope this helps!